# iframe doesn't obey color styling

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

As you can see [here](https://github.com/programmin1/DevTools-Tweaks/blob/master/content/netWinOverlay.js), I have set up an addon to replace some contents of the network-inspect-popup with pretty-printed values. The odd thing is, I'm setting background of both the iframe and the inner document (`background;#FFF`), but it still shows the bluish background of the net-inspector. What's wrong with this, and why does DOM Inspector addon not even let me inspect to see what's wrong here?

Comment: Checkout and build that project. Addon shows background blue color, not white.

Comment: Honestly, I'm too lazy to figure out from the code where and under what conditions your `<iframe>` gets displayed... It might be obvious to you, but it isn't to me.

Comment: It shows when you check "logging" under net, in Firefox web console, then post an ajax request and click it.

Comment: Looks like the body has a different background-color than expected in style attr, although data has the background:white. DOM inspector works although it thinks the frame is content, although it is really Chrome.

Comment: Oops, it looks like it's because the load event bubbles up to the outer window - shouldn't that not happen for content iframes? My listener is adding that color.

Comment: Should have refreshed the comment section. Seems found our yourself while I still composed my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [own code](https://github.com/programmin1/DevTools-Tweaks/blob/master/content/netWinOverlay.js#L26) overrides your own style. You have:

```
netPanel.iframe.addEventListener('load',function(event) {
  var doc = event.originalTarget;
  doc.body.style.backgroundColor='rgb(85,87,128)';
  // ...
}, true);
```

This event listener will be called for all `load` events bubbling in the `netPanel.iframe` DOM, and that includes the load event the iframe document you insert creates. Change your code to first check the `load` is actually coming from a document you want to "overlay".

PS: You can actually use the DOM Inspector. But note that the "window" is not actually a window, but a `<panel>` in under the `browser.xul` top-level DOM.